# Open-source generic web service to database interface?

Tags: php, mysql, database, web-services, interface

I'm looking for a thin, generic layer (probably written in PHP) that sits between a database (probably MySQL) and web service clients (which could be anything).  I imagine there would be config files of some sort that tell it how to map web service requests to database queries (or other DB commands).  It would also need to handle authentication and authorization, of course.

I've done some googling but failed to find anything that fits the bill.  Can anyone suggest something like this?

Comment: Nope.  We started to write our own, but then the winds shifted and we ended up not needing it after all.

Answer (score 2):

This is the right framework for your needs - http://sourceforge.net/projects/phprestsql/

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are all sorts of PHP database frameworks that may very well fit the bill.

Most obvious is PDO, which is really just a set of classes for working with the database. It's baked into PHP 5.1+ so it doesn't even require a download.

Others are more complete, and do all sorts of work for you.

- [Prado](http://www.xisc.com/) (Which gained features and size with the [latest](http://www.pradosoft.com/) [forks](http://www.yiiframework.com/))
- [Zend_DB](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.html)

And search Google for a massively large list.
Hope that helps.

Answer (score -2):

[phpMyAdmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php) might be what you are looking for.

Comment: It would be nice to know what the down vote was for.  From what the question asked it seems to me that phpMyAdmin would indeed fit the bill.

Comment: i didnt vote you down but it was probably because phpmyadmin is just an admin interface. It doesnt handle web service requests.

Comment: I guess I didn't understand the question as well as I thought.

Comment: Thanks for trying, though; it's my fault for being unclear.  I don't need an admin interface -- I'm happy configuring the DB via the command line as usual.  What I want is something that provides web service (probably a REST API) for whatever DB operations an app might need, those operations being configurable via some sort of simple (non-coding) setup files.

Comment: No problem, I just like to see a comment if my answer gets down voted so I know what I said wrong, that way I do not go spreading bad info around.